# How to run zypper commands in SUSE container on non-SUSE host OS (if even possible?)

Tags: docker, opensuse, zypper

I'm trying to create support for my program on the SUSE OS...by creating a docker container with my base image/layer being SUSE and then installing my program and any dependent packages via zypper.

I'm on windows but I've `Switched to Linux Containers`. When I run my container the container's OS is SUSE but the problem is with zypper...the commands fail to install, update, etc

Here's my docker file which I'm using the build the image for the container:

```
FROM registry.suse.com/suse/sle15
```

In the container this creates I do:

```
zypper update -y
```

which gives this error:

```
Problem retrieving the repository index file for service 'container-suseconnect-zypp':
[container-suseconnect-zypp|file:/usr/lib/zypp/plugins/services/container-suseconnect-zypp]
Warning: Skipping service 'container-suseconnect-zypp' because of the above error.
Loading repository data...
Warning: No repositories defined. Operating only with the installed resolvables. Nothing can be installed.
Reading installed packages...
Nothing to do.
```

Doing `zypper install libcurl` also gives a similar error and doesn't install anything.

My question: is it possible to use zypper if my host OS isn't SUSE? I've found examples of referencing repositories with zypper if the host OS is SUSE but I'm not sure how to do so if the host OS isn't SUSE

Note: I plan to put the zypper commands in the docker file, I'm just running it in the container now to more clearly see what's happening.

Comment: try with `FROM opensuse/leap:15.2`

Comment: @ChrisMaes thank you! This solved it for me! I need to also support my program on `SLES 12 SP5`, `SLES 12 SP4` and `SLES 12 SP3`. Looking at the opensuse/leap images on docker hub I see that `SLES 12 SP3` actually maps to `opensuse/leap:42.3`. I can't find images with tags 42.4 and 42.5 though, would you have any insight for that?

Comment: SLES is the paying variant of opensuse, so I don't know if they map completely...